# How can I label a GPG key I received

Tags: gnupg

I got a public GPG key from John Doe, but I know him better as computer_lemon2929 on superuser.com.  Every time I need to encrypt something to him or come across a signed commit or whatever of his I can't remember who John Doe is/which key to use.

How can I change the displayed name for his key in my keyring to computer_lemon2929?